# Can't remove adware from PC

Tags: browser, virus, adware

People please help me to remove this Qone8 adware. I don't know even what software installed it. No uninstaller, no extesion. Tried to reset all browsers, no way. It starts with browser:

[image]

Comment: If it comes with a software, remove the original software first as a start. I also found this as the first link on google to remove Qone8 - http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-start-qone8-virus/ - Mind you you can still access google by www.google.com and do you search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: If this occurss after the virus is removed, then. Open firefox, click on the search box in the top right (CTRL E), click the drop down list and click Manage Search Engine List. Then see if you can remove it from the list. After, click on ALT, then Tools, then Options. In the General tab, ensure the home page is set to something you want.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced that specific piece of malicious software, but I've yet to encounter something that survives ComboFix:

www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/‎

You'll need to uninstall your Anti-Virus software before running it, I'd advise doing so only in Safe Mode and then immediately re-install your AV.